# Apache HTTP Server and Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, jenkins, apache2, sonarqube

I have a ubuntu server setup on Amazon EC2 where I have jenkins and sonar installed

I installed jenkins using apt-get and sonar by downloading the relevant package from their website

When these services start up, I can get to jenkins via the url `http://ec2-1-2-3-4:8080` and sonar with the url `http://ec2-1-2-3-4:9000`

Using Apache HTTP Server, is it possible to set it up to navigate to jenkins and sonar using the following urls?

```
http://ec2-1-2-3-4/jenkins
http://ec2-1-2-3-4/sonar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you have to use mod_proxy. i did the same for my Jira install. Here is the Vhost.

```
ServerName  jira.chidgey.me
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://jira.chidgey.me:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://jira.chidgey.me:8080/

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/jira.chidgey.me/httpdocs
```